# What is the meaning of 'up to me'?

Tags: word-meaning

> *When I sit to write, I first think about what I would write if the choice of topic were **up to me***.

I googled to search the meaning of *up to me*. I got a song starting with it, but I didn't find its meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look up [***up to***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/up-to?q=up+to):

> the responsibility or choice of (someone): '*It was up to them to gauge
>   the problem*', '*No one is forcing them to make a difference here, it is really up to individual choice*'

And it could mean *[decided by someone](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/up+to)*.

"If the choice of topic were up to me" could be rephrased to:

> '*if I had the responsibility to choose a topic*', '*if I were responsible for choosing a topic*' or '*if I were (was) the one to decide what (which) topic to choose*'

[Oxford Online Dictionary, The Free Dictionary]

Answer (score 5):

In this context, it  means "if the decision was mine to make", if it was my responsibility to choose.

[Chambers entry:](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=up&title=21st)

> **up to someone**: their responsibility; dependent on them • It's up to you.